# Fill the ComboBox with Columns from table to another comboBox - c#

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I got some problem, typically not errors but it's not showing to my `comboBox`

Here's my code and tried many times but it doesn't show.

```
using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC; Initial Catalog=StudentDB; Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    con2.Open();
    using (SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Northwind.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'"+comboBox3.Text+"' ", con2))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader2 = com2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            comboBox4.Items.Clear();
            while (reader2.Read())

            {
                comboBox4.Items.Add((string)reader2["COLUMN_NAME"]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I searched with the similar topic but it still doesn't work for me..

Any idea what is the wrong with the following code above?

Comment: You sure your query returns any rows? How do you call your code, on which event? Can you put breakpoint on your com2 and make sure your sqlCommand is set properly? Also, check out prepared statements when you got time, it's important

Comment: I already said what I mean, but I guess this is the problem..

comboBox4.Items.Add((string)reader2["COLUMN_NAME"]);

I don't think this code works..

Comment: Try like this `comboBox4.Items.Add(reader2["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());`